# web audio api rain droplets noise

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api, webapi

I'm trying to create an audio that sounds like rain on a window in javascript web audio API. All I have so far is white noise which kind of sounds like a lot of background rain, but i'd like to code the individual droplets. However, I really haven't been able to make droopy sounds like water and I was wondering if anyone had a suggestion on what this piece of code would look like? Right now I have noise in an audio context that I've passed through a bunch of different filters but I can't make it sound like actual water. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to code rain in web audio API? Thank you very much, this is for a school project.

Comment: Check out https://musiclab.chromeexperiments.com/ and reach out to some of the folks who worked on that.  They are great and can point you in the right direction!